# python get count of non-empty JSON subarrays

Tags: python, arrays, json

How can I count the number of non-empty `dailyemails` in the following json?

```
{
   "templates":[
      {
         "id":"2c1d99d9b6b2fb417601d24c10c9b041a7d6f37b",
         "dailyemails":[
            "saaa@aa.com",
            "aaa.aaa@gmail.com"
         ],
         "name":"Registration Report"             
      },
      {
         "id":"45s4dsf4qdgze5zef1z3e2f1zevcd5s6sdfsdfsdf",
         "dailyemails":[
         ],
         "name":"Presentation"             
      },
      {
         "id":"7d7cc642ca13cc4a998cad364dfe8e623fd95ae3",
         "dailyemails":[
            "saaa@ss.com"
         ],
         "name":"Live Report"
      }

   ]
}
```

In Javascript, I am doing it like this:

```
var count = myArray.reduce((c, o) => c + (o.dailyemails.length? 1: 0), 0);
```

How can I read the number of non-empty `dailyemails` in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something similar

```
import json
myArray = json.loads(json_string)["templates"]
count = sum(map(lambda x: bool(x["dailyemails"]), myArray))
```

Or, almost word-by-word translation:

```
count = reduce(lambda c, o: c + (1 if o["dailyemails"] else 0), myArray, 0)
```

Edit: missing closing `)`, and even more literal translation.

Answer (score 1):

```
count_non_empty_dailyemails = 0
for template in json_text['templates']:
  if template['dailyemails']:
     count_non_empty_dailyemails +=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

`len([item for item in js['templates'] if item['dailyemails']])`

Answer (score 1):

a one-liner with list comprehension.

```
print len([i['dailyemails'] for i in  a["templates"] if len(i['dailyemails']) < 1])
```

https://repl.it/H6D6